# Java NIO/SSL/Client state management

Tags: java, ssl

I previously posted a question regarding some code which I had inherited (the fellow who wrote it passed away), that I needed help on. I immediately got shot down because I hadn't written the code myself, and didn't really understand the code.  If this is not the right forum, can someone please tell me where I can post the code (which I now need to modify) and get some help? Thanks

Comment: That's not why you got "shot down", and this question itself does not belong here; I'm voting to migrate it to meta, where it is probably on-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure what "meta" is.

Comment: [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is the site where Stack Overflow itself is discussed. Questions about what to do about issues with existing questions on Stack Overflow, for example, are posted there. This might apply to your question here.